# CSS3 increasing delay effect?

Tags: css, animation, delay

I have an unordered list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Monkey</li>
    <li>Sun</li>
    <li>Moon</li>
    <li>Movies</li>
</ul>
```

And a scale in animation:

```
ul li {
    animation           : scale-in 1s;
}

@keyframes scale-in
{
    0% { 
        opacity             : 0;
        -webkit-transform   : scale(0.5);
    }
    20% {
        opacity             : 0;
        -webkit-transform   : scale(0.5);
    }
    100% {
        opacity             : 1;
        -webkit-transform   : scale(1.0);
    }
}
```

Now I like the delay of each element to be 1 second apart from each other. So first item appears immediately, second 1sec delay, third 2sec delay, etc.

Is there a neat way to do this, perhaps using the nth selector? or do I actually have to write it out like `ul li:nth-child(1) { delay : 1s; } ul li:nth-child(2) { delay : 2s; }`

Comment: You're much better off using Javascript for this, CSS3 isn't the easiest way to express this, and you'd be lucky if it even works in all the latest versions of the major browsers, let alone the old.

Comment: It's just a nice effect, I don't mind that old browsers won't see the effect (those people should just update their browsers!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to do this with CSS3 other than the way you suggested. Since there is no real way to do math, or to loop through things, it's not really possible other than writing it out by hand.

I would have to second NightCracker's JS suggestion. You don't have to necessarily write the animation itself with JS, but you could fire it using JS. Something as simple as using a While loop with a incremental counter should do the trick.

In the end though, you're just saving a few lines of code versus just writing it out in CSS. Functionality wise it would still be the same, especially if cross browser compatibility is not a concern.

Comment: I think you might be right, although it would be nice if you could add simple math formula's to css such as animation-delay:(n+1)s where n is the index of the element (as seen in nth-child).